# Is there a name for these lines on a plot?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, scatterplot

I'm working with plots for which I'm finding the maximum point and labelling the x and y values at which it occurs:

[image]

My question is, is there an 'official' name for the red dashed lines that extend from the point to each of the axes?

Comment: Do you mean any set of vertical-and-horizontal reference lines that mark some particular chosen $x$ (abscissa) and its corresponding $y$, (ordinate) - not necessarily marking the functional-mode as in the diagram - or do you mean a term for the specific $x$-that-maximizes $y=f(x)$ (i.e. the *argmax*) and its corresponding $y$ (the function mode / maximum)?

Comment: @Glen_b I meant in general, any set of horizontal and vertical lines marking a point.

Comment: Personally, I tend to say "a pair of horizontal and vertical reference lines" but there may well be some other term.

Comment: With a linear plateau model, the terms "critical x" and "plateau" are used.  Here, you might use "critical x" and "maximum" ?  Or maybe "model maximum" and "x corresponding to the model maximum" ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico I'm interested in the term for the red dashed reference lines extending to the axes, not the point they're highlighting.

Comment: Okay.  In that case, I don't know of anything other than e.g. "red dashed horizontal line", or "reference line" sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own impression and the consensus here is that the answer is **no**, there is no specific name for these reference lines.